# how to create bar button or UIButton in tableview header in swift 2.2?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I want to create a `UIBarButtonItem` or `UIButton` in `UITableview` header so when I click on the `UITableview` header button it should go to the other `UIViewcontroller`. How can I achieve this programmatically?

Comment: can you show the screen shot which type u need

Comment: please add code or pictures of what you have done so far

Comment: why you choose tableheader , directly add in navigation bar right button

Comment: i already taken two button on the navigation bar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

do like

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? 
{
```

> initially get the frame of your Tableview

```
let frame: CGRect = tableView.frame
```

> set the frame for UIbutton where is comes in View

```
let DoneBut: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(100, 0, 200, 50)) //frame.size.width - 60
DoneBut.setTitle("Done", forState: .Normal)
DoneBut.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

> if you are using swift 2.2 call the selector as follows

```
 DoneBut.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

> if you are using swift 2.1 call the selector as follows

```
DoneBut.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonTapped:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonTapped:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

> create the UIView reason viewforHeader returns UIView and add button to that subView

```
 let headerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height))
headerView.addSubview(DoneBut)
return headerView
}
```

> call method like

```
func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
//Button Tapped and open your another ViewController

}
```

**Updated answer**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
{

    let frame: CGRect = tableView.frame


    let DoneBut: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(frame.size.width - 200, 0, 150, 50)) //
    DoneBut.setTitle("Done", forState: .Normal)
    DoneBut.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    DoneBut.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    DoneBut.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    let headerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height))
      headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    headerView.addSubview(DoneBut)
    return headerView
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50.0
}

func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    //Button Tapped and open your another ViewController

}
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: table view is coming white button is not visible

Comment: try this `let DoneBut: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(100, 0, 200, 50)) `

Comment: i given the header background color also but still nothing is coming

Comment: can you send the project I wil check

Comment: @anand - what is this , else show the full code

Comment: sorry, where can i sent you my code??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120410/discussion-between-anand-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: That is what I want! Is it better to put the header view and button initialization code outside of `viewForHeaderInSection`? e.g. use `lazy var closure` to create this header view.

Answer (score 2):

Hi guys this is working for.May be this helpful for you.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
   return 50
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {    
   let frame: CGRect = tableView.frame
   let DoneBut: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(200, 0, 200, 50))
   DoneBut.setTitle("+", forState: .Normal)
   DoneBut.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
   DoneBut.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DetailViewController.pressed(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
   let headerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.height, frame.size.width))
   headerView.addSubview(DoneBut)
   return headerView
}


func pressed(sender: UIButton!) {
  print("Hello");    
  let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)    
  let qutationViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newWorkViewController") as! NewWorkViewController
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(qutationViewController, animated: true)            
}
```